# Convert cell (title) in drop-down cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to put the following in a VBA-Excel code.

Imagine I have a 3-column spreadsheet like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
+-----Info1---|---Info2---|---Title1---|---Title2---|---Title3----+
+  50         | 40        |   =B2*2    | =C3*4      | = D2*3      +
+  80         | 24        |   =B3*2    | =C4*4      | = D3*3      +
+  43         | 66        |   =B4*     | =C5*4      | = D4*3      +
+  104        | 88        |   =B5*2    | =C6*4      | = D5*3      +
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to transform *Title1*, *Title2* and *Title3* from simple text-cells to drop-down menu cells, with options like: "Sort A-Z", "Sort Z-A", having the option to select just the cells that are equal to some number or things like that.

How can I do that? And it also would be nice if I could change the design of those cells (like when converting them in the Design menu)

Comment: maybe make it a structured table ...?

Comment: I don't know if I understood what you said, but I would like to keep the format of the spreadsheet, if it's possible. How can I do that in VBA?

Comment: Select any cell in the '3-column spreadsheet' then choose Insert, Tables, Table and follow directions.

Comment: Jeeped, the idea is to do it in VBA (macros), not manually. Thanks :)

Comment: So record yourself doing it manually and then tap alt+f11 and clean up the resulting code.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeeped has stated.

You can select any cell in your range

[image: Cell in range]

Then press Ctrl + T to turn it into an Excel table (or insert table and use your range as source)

You can the get a set of filters for the header row (assuming you select my table has headers) where you can apply your filter on the data e.g. > , = ...

[image: Applying filter]

The moment you create your table a Design tab should appear showing different designs you can apply to your table. See different coloured table outlines in image.

[image: Table styles in different colours at top]

The exact look may differ as I am on a mac.

The cells where you have formulas: You only need to put the formula in one cell in the column and it will autofill for the rest. So, good if you want to apply the same formula for each row in the column; which it appears you do.

Google can show you the way with using these tools.

Comment: @Accexcessel - So record yourself doing it manually and then tap alt+f11 and clean up the resulting code.